# Get element at position with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to either run or get the same functionality provided by `document.elementFromPoint` using a Selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript for that:

```
element = driver.execute_script("""
return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
""", x, y)
```

This assumes that `x` and `y` are set to integer values. The arguments you pass to `execute_script` after the first argument become `arguments[0], arguments[1]`, etc. on the JavaScript side. (This is just the good old [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). Selenium wraps the JavaScript code you give to `execute_script` in a function.) The `element` will either be an instance of `WebElement` or `None` if nothing could be found. According to the [MDN page on this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) a `None` value will happen if:

> If the specified point is outside the visible bounds of the document or either coordinate is negative, the result is `null`.

JavaScript `null` becomes `None` in Python.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! If anyone knows of a way to do it without reaching into the JS on the page, that would be preferred, but this will work, as well.

Comment: With JavaScript this will only work if you have no frame or iframe on the page. Otherwise cross site scripting protection in the browser prohibits accessing another frame in JavaScript. The correct solution would be to implement this in the driver.

Comment: @Elmue I've just tried it in Chrome, on a page that loads another site in an `iframe`. It works.

Comment: It is much more complicated if you want to respect also frames and iframes. I posted a working code in C# that you find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910534/executing-javascript-elementfrompoint-through-selenium-driver/32574543#32574543