# Executing Javascript elementFromPoint through Selenium driver

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to implement an "object picker" to my Selenium based framework as is common on most commercial automation tools. To do this I am using a Javascript command to find the element at the mouse location, but I am not getting the element I expect.

If I am using ChromeDriver or InternetExplorerDriver the script always returns the header object. No matter what webpage I look at or the position of the mouse. Although it sounds like the script is taking the coordinates 0, 0 instead of the mouse position I have confirmed that Cursor.Position is sending the correct values.

If I am using FirefoxDriver I get an exception:

```
"Argument 1 of Document.elementFromPoint is not a finite floating-point value. (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)"
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
    private void OnHovering()
    {
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control)
        {
            IWebElement ele = null;
            try
            {
                // Find the element at the mouse position
                if (driver is IJavaScriptExecutor)
                    ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
                        "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", 
                        new int[] { Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y });

                // Select the element found
                if (ele != null)
                    SelectElement(ele);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you actually move the mouse to an element? Thanks.

Comment: Also, do you have iframe elements on a page?

Comment: With the Mouse ;-)  the function occurs within a Timer tick. If the user is holding ctrl, the element under the mouse gets selected

Comment: I am not the developer of the webpage, but I tried many different webpages... www.nab.com.au, www.microsoft.com, www.google.com. No matter what the site is I get the header returned. Cursor.Position.X and Cursor.Position.Y are the correct values, it just seems that I am not passing them correctly to the "ExecuteScript" method.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I've just reproduced the problem using Python bindings and SO site as a target - no matter what the coordinates are, the header element is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually about how you are passing the coordinates into the script. *Script arguments has to be specified separately as separate `ExecuteScript()` arguments*. What was happening in your case is that you have basically specified one `x` argument which made it think that `y` should be considered a default `0` value. And at `y=0` there is usually a header.

Instead of:

```
ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
                        "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", 
                        new int[] { Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y });
```

You should do:

```
ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
                        "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", 
                        Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe, you're right that this was the problem. But the documentation for C# is `object IJavaScriptExecuter.ExecuteScript(string script, params object[] args)`. Is the documentation wrong or am I reading it wrong? To me that means that the second parameter should be an array of arguments.

Comment: @Scotty yeah, this is quite confusing I agree.

Answer (score 2):

The code from alecxe works in most cases, but it will fail if the page contains frames or iframes.

Much more code is required to respect also frames / iframes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the element at the viewport coordinates X, Y
/// </summary>
static public RemoteWebElement GetElementFromPoint(RemoteWebDriver i_Driver, int X, int Y)
{
    while (true)
    {
        String s_Script = "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);";

        RemoteWebElement i_Elem = (RemoteWebElement)i_Driver.ExecuteScript(s_Script, X, Y);
        if (i_Elem == null)
            return null;

        if (i_Elem.TagName != "frame" && i_Elem.TagName != "iframe")
            return i_Elem;

        Point p_Pos = GetElementPosition(i_Elem);
        X -= p_Pos.X;
        Y -= p_Pos.Y;

        i_Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(i_Elem);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the position of the top/left corner of the Element in the document.
/// NOTE: RemoteWebElement.Location is always measured from the top of the document and ignores the scroll position.
/// </summary>
static public Point GetElementPosition(RemoteWebElement i_Elem)
{
    String s_Script = "var X, Y; "
                    + "if (window.pageYOffset) " // supported by most browsers 
                    + "{ "
                    + "  X = window.pageXOffset; "
                    + "  Y = window.pageYOffset; "
                    + "} "
                    + "else " // Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8
                    + "{ "
                    + "  var  Elem = document.documentElement; "         // <html> node (IE with DOCTYPE)
                    + "  if (!Elem.clientHeight) Elem = document.body; " // <body> node (IE in quirks mode)
                    + "  X = Elem.scrollLeft; "
                    + "  Y = Elem.scrollTop; "
                    + "} "
                    + "return new Array(X, Y);";

    RemoteWebDriver i_Driver = (RemoteWebDriver)i_Elem.WrappedDriver;
    IList<Object>   i_Coord  = (IList<Object>)  i_Driver.ExecuteScript(s_Script);

    int s32_ScrollX = Convert.ToInt32(i_Coord[0]);
    int s32_ScrollY = Convert.ToInt32(i_Coord[1]);

    return new Point(i_Elem.Location.X - s32_ScrollX,
                     i_Elem.Location.Y - s32_ScrollY);
}
```

This should be implemented in the WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well. The reason it was being thrown I found out was because the element I was trying to get the location of was hidden (had the attribute display:none). And therefore didn't have a location.